# Is Shannon Half-Sky gone forever if she dies?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

I brought her on the mission to the mental asylum, and she and another runner I hired (DeMorgana) died.

When I hired runners for the next mission, DeMorgana was still on the list (she costs nuyen to hire) but Shannon wasn't. Are the ones that cost 0 nuyen gone forever if they die?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the runners that cost 0¥ are restricted to certain missions. I am Not 100% sure if shannon will reappear later, but for now you wont be able to hire her again. She basically helps you for free on your next run After you help her, and then goes her own ways.

To answer the essence of your question: no, Runners will not disappear from the game if they get taken out during a Mission, they will be available for hire later on, but special npcs (e.g. Coyote or Shannon) might simply not be available for a Mission.